# Change specific product cart item name in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I am using the following code to change product names on checkout page, but I need to do it for only one product. I am not able to figure out how to target a specific product ID:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_cart_items_prices', 10, 1 );
function custom_cart_items_prices( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        // Get the product name (Added Woocommerce 3+ compatibility)
        $original_name = method_exists( $product, 'get_name' ) ? $product->get_name() : $product->post->post_title;

        // SET THE NEW NAME
        $new_name = 'mydesiredproductname';

        // Set the new name (WooCommerce versions 2.5.x to 3+)
        if( method_exists( $product, 'set_name' ) )
            $product->set_name( $new_name );
        else
            $product->post->post_title = $new_name;
    }
}
```

The code changes ALL the product names on WooCommerce checkout page to the new product name. But I need to do it for a specific product only (product with ID: 134443).

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified, targeting a specific product to change its name. Try:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_specific_cart_item_name' );
function change_specific_cart_item_name( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $targeted_id = 134443; // HERE set the targeted product ID
    $new_name    = "The new product name"; // HERE set the desired new product name

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == $targeted_id ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_name($new_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.